# Configuration JSON file not found after build react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react application which is relying on a configuration json file for its execution. Plan is to update the JSON file after build for different environment. Never tried before.

So I imported my JSON file like this

```
import data from './config.json'
```

So I was able to use the json properties in my application TS file while debugging from VS.

But I tried to build the app, but I cant find that file in any of the build path.

What I did wrong? Or how can I achieve above requirement.

Ultimately I need to update my JSON file while deploying into different environments which is I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

During the build process your .json file will be incorporated into the .js files. I don't know many details about this, but I believe that it is not possible to do what you want.

What might help you is the use of environment variables. But it will still be necessary specific builds for each environment.