# Dynamic configuration for MSAL from JSON file in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement authentication for my react application  and I have created a authConfig.ts file with below configuration

```
import data from './config.json'

export const msalConfig = {

    auth: {
        clientId: data.clientId,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${data.tenantId}`,
        redirectUri: data.redirectUri
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
    system: {   
        loggerOptions: {    
            loggerCallback: (level:any, message:string, containsPii:any) => {   
                if (containsPii) {      
                    return;     
                }       
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                    default:
                        return;
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }
};
```

This is working fine,but its adding the JSON data into the JS file (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291195/954093) on my another question)

So I am not able to use the real purpose of JSON file which is to switch the configuration after build.

But based on this nice answer I guess I can get the JSON file values at runtime.. (Not tried)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291195/954093

But my challenge is how can I implement below thing in my authconfig.ts file since its just exporting the configuration constants

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('settings.json').then(response => {
        response.json().then(settings => {
            // instead of setting state you can use it any other way
            setState({settings: settings});
        })
    })
})
```

So ultimately I need my JSON file settings for client ID, tenantID etc to be get in that authConfig.ts file at runtime irrespective of what ever there in that config.json file while build.

Answer (score 2):

Create a hook to load data from `json`

```
const useConfig = () => {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAsync = async () => {
      const sessionConfig = sessionStorage.getItem("config");
      if (sessionConfig) {
        setConfig(JSON.parse(sessionConfig));
        return;
      }

      const response = await fetch("config.json");
      const json = await response.json();
      setConfig(json);
      sessionStorage.setItem("config", JSON.stringify(json));
    };
    loadAsync();
  }, []);

  return [config];
};

export default useConfig;
```

Load config into `MsalProvider`

```
    const MyProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [config] = useConfig();
  if (!config?.ui?.auth) return <>Loading config...</>;

  // MSAL configuration
  const configuration: Configuration = {
    auth: config.ui.auth,
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
  };

  const pca = new PublicClientApplication(configuration);

  return <MsalProvider instance={pca}>{props.children}</MsalProvider>;
};
```

Finally:

```
<MyProvider>
      <MsalAuthenticationTemplate interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect}>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
          <MyApiProvider>
            <App />
          </MyApiProvider>
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
    </MyProvider>
```